# React-native Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details

Tags: javascript, react-native, gradle

I need help with my first React-native app.
It generates

C:\Users\Bradburry\Downloads\Project Vlogee\Hasura>react-native run-android
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...

> Configure project :app
>   WARNING: The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
>   Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018..

C:\Users\Bradburry.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\eaf5e02e0fb5007b45b00a347d77a822\res\values-v24\values-v24.xml:3:5-157: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

C:\Users\Bradburry.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\eaf5e02e0fb5007b45b00a347d77a822\res\values-v24\values-v24.xml:4:5-135: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

C:\Users\Bradburry.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\eaf5e02e0fb5007b45b00a347d77a822\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 32s
13 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 10 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Obviously `TextAppearanceMaterial.Widget.Button.Button.Colored` is missing, but without the code we can't help..

Comment: It's the first code for phone installation I haven't written anything yet it just reaches 40% upon build then it generates the error.

Comment: I have edited it ☝

Comment: Whats your Compile SDK & Build Tool Version in your build.gradle file?...Possibly a simple version mismatch.

Comment: BuildToolVersion = 27.0.3 , minSdkversion = 16,  CompileSdkVersion = 23 , targetSdkVersion = 23, supportLibVersion = 27.1.1